# How Can I render the Hosptal?

Tags: python, django

How to show the Hospital here? (https://ibb.co/Xkn58yK)

```
    blood/models
    
    from django.db import models
    
    class Patient(models.Model):
        patient_id = models.CharField(max_length= 1000, null= True)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length= 50,  null = True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null = True, blank=True)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, null= True, blank=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True, blank=True)
        hospitals = models.ManyToManyField(Hospital)
        BLOOD_TYPE = (
            ('O+','O+'),
            ('O-','O-'),
            ('A+','A+'),
            ('A-','A-'),
            ('B+','B+'),
            ('B-','B-'),
            ('AB+','AB+'),
            ('AB-','AB-'),
            )
        patient_blood = models.CharField(max_length=5,  null = True , choices=BLOOD_TYPE)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return '{} {} {} {}' .format(self.first_name, self.last_name, "-", self.patient_id)
    
    
    
    
    class Hospital(models.Model):
        hospital = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=100,  null = True, blank=True)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, null= True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.hospital
```

views.py

```
    blood/views
    
    
    
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from .forms import *
    
    def PatientPage(request):
    
        patients = Patient.objects.all()
        hospitals = Hospital.objects.all()
    
        context = {
        'patients':patients,
        'hospitals':hospitals,
        }
        return render(request, 'blood/patients.html', context)
```

I can query the rest, only the hospital left

```
 {% for id in patients %}
        <tr>
<td>{{id.hospitals}}</td>
 </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

This is the HTML section, I listed the rest, but I can't do the ManyToManyField. The only problem is how can I show the hospital chosen by the patient

I am just starting to learn, so I'm sorry

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please _only_ host images using the official image host. The one you have used looks super sketchy and will probably stop hosting this image at some point. Questions on SO are meant to help others in the future, as well as you.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model does not seem to be correct, but based on the current model, this may work:

```
 {% for p in patients %}
  <table>
     <tr><td>Date Registered</td><td>Hospital</td><td>Blood Type</td></tr>
    {{for h in p.hospitals}}
        <tr><td>{{p.date_created}}</td><td>{{h.hospital}}</td><td>{{p.patient_blood}}</td></tr>
    {{endfor}}
  </table>
  {% endfor %}
```